# How to present footer content on certain pages using an if statement

Tags: php, html

I am new to php and I want to only show specific footer content on 2 pages.

I know I would use an if statement, but I don't know if there is way in php to know what page is being displayed.

Here is the footer.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer.
 *
 * Contains the closing of the id=main div and all content after
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Eleven
 * @since Twenty Eleven 1.0
 */
?>

    </div><!-- #main -->

    <footer id="colophon" role="contentinfo">

            <?php
                /* A sidebar in the footer? Yep. You can can customize
                 * your footer with three columns of widgets.
                 */
                get_sidebar( 'footer' );
            ?>

            <div class="boli-better">
<h1 class="description-title">WHY IS BOLI BETTER?</h1>
<div class="feature feature-item-248"><img class="main" src="http://www.btylus.com/wp-content/uploads/uclaproduct.png" alt="" />
<div class="feature_description">
<div class="feature_description_header">
<h2 class="descript-heading">PERFECTLY WEIGHTED</h2>
</div>
<div class="feature_description_content">

Touch screens have simplified technology, but there has yet to be a way to capture the precision of a calligrapher or the stroke of an artist. Not only should it meet your needs, but a stylus should have style.

</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="feature feature-item-252"><img class="main" src="http://www.bylus.com/wp-content/uploads/bolitip.png" alt="" width="640" height="301" />
<div class="feature_description">
<div class="feature_description_header">
<h2 class="descript-heading">PEN-LIKE PRECISION</h2>
</div>
<div class="feature_description_content">

Your stylus should be as sharp as your ideas. The thin and clear disc gives you the accuracy you want in a digital pen.

</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="feature feature-item-254">

<img class="main" src="http://www.bylus.com/wp-content/uploads/blueproduct.png" alt="" />
<div class="feature_description">
<div class="feature_description_header">
<h2 class="descript-heading">BALL POINT</h2>
</div>
<div class="feature_description_content">

Hold your stylus at the angle you’re most comfortable with. Jot gives you the freedom to write or sketch like you’re used to.

</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="feature feature-item-256">

<img class="main" src="http://www.btylus.com/wp-content/uploads/greenproduct.png" alt="" />
<div class="feature_description">
<div class="feature_description_header">
<h2 class="descript-heading">HEAVY METAL</h2>
</div>
<div class="feature_description_content">

Once Jot is in your grip, the quality is unmistakable. The durable aluminum and steel gives Jot superior conductivity and craftsmanship comparable to any luxury pen.

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

            <div id="site-generator">

                <strong id="footertext">Copyright Boli Stylus 2011</strong> 
                <a href="http://www.blus.com/contact-us" id="footertext" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a> 
                <a href="http://www.btylus.com/terms" id="footertext" title="Terms">Terms</a>
            </div>
    </footer><!-- #colophon -->
</div><!-- #page -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Ok, so this is what I came up with, but when I add this code to the footer.php, the entire footer doesn't appear on the site.

I'm sure I just made an elementary mistake so thanks for the help in advance!

```
<?php

$page = 'shop';
if (is_page($page)) { ?>

<div class="boli-better">
<h1 class="description-title">WHY IS BOLI BETTER?</h1>
<div class="feature feature-item-248"><img class="main" src="http://www.bylus.com/wp-content/uploads/uclaproduct.png" alt="" />
<div class="feature_description">
<div class="feature_description_header">
<h2 class="descript-heading">PERFECTLY WEIGHTED</h2>
</div>
<div class="feature_description_content">

Touch screens have simplified technology, but there has yet to be a way to capture the precision of a calligrapher or the stroke of an artist. Not only should it meet your needs, but a stylus should have style.

</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="feature feature-item-252"><img class="main" src="http://www.bylus.com/wp-content/uploads/bolitip.png" alt="" width="640" height="301" />
<div class="feature_description">
<div class="feature_description_header">
<h2 class="descript-heading">PEN-LIKE PRECISION</h2>
</div>
<div class="feature_description_content">

Your stylus should be as sharp as your ideas. The thin and clear disc gives you the accuracy you want in a digital pen.

</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="feature feature-item-254">

<img class="main" src="http://www.btylus.com/wp-content/uploads/blueproduct.png" alt="" />
<div class="feature_description">
<div class="feature_description_header">
<h2 class="descript-heading">BALL POINT</h2>
</div>
<div class="feature_description_content">

Hold your stylus at the angle you’re most comfortable with. Jot gives you the freedom to write or sketch like you’re used to.

</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="feature feature-item-256">

<img class="main" src="http://www.bylus.com/wp-content/uploads/greenproduct.png" alt="" />
<div class="feature_description">
<div class="feature_description_header">
<h2 class="descript-heading">HEAVY METAL</h2>
</div>
<div class="feature_description_content">

Once Jot is in your grip, the quality is unmistakable. The durable aluminum and steel gives Jot superior conductivity and craftsmanship comparable to any luxury pen.

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>;

<?php 
}
?>
```

Comment: Please post the code relevant to the question. Ideally, **in addition** to the code in the question body itself, please add a [codepad](http://codepad.org) example of your problem. It will help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at PHP's [server variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). You are probably looking for `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/index.php") {
   echo "My stuff to show on /index.php";
}
```

Comment: @novicePrgrmr Unfortunately I haven no experience of WP, but based on the documentation, my best guess is this: `wp_reset_query(); if (is_page("shop")) { // Do your thing }`. Have you tried my example, without using the WP-specific functions?

Comment: @novicePrgrmr Sweet! Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the WP Codex. I thing is_page() is what you are looking for: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page

Comment: I added my failed code using is_page() to the questions if you could take a look at it.

Comment: I don't think it works like that, you don't need to set a variable. WP figures it out for you. Read this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_PAGE_Page

Comment: I don't think it works with the name of the file, but rather the slug name. From Codex: 'is_page( 'about-me' ) 
When the Page with a post_name (slug) of "about-me" is being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can either set a special variable on pages where you would like to check it (and use it in an if statement for the footer), or use the answer by @Christofer Eliasson, which uses the server's REQUEST_URI variable

Answer (score 0):

what you want is:

```
<?php
     if (is_page(array('page1','page2'))) {
       <!-- Fotter content displayed here --> 
     }
?>
```